# How to draw a running track on a canvas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

I am trying to make a basic track with JavaScript and HTML 5 like the image below.

[image]

Is it possible to do this programmatically or should I use an image to loop it? The curve of the track will be changing.

I'm thinking about using a PNG image and `drawImage` to render the canvas. I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it.

What would be the optimal method?

Comment: You could just use paths, both simple, straight-line ones and bezier curves. For the picture you show, I'd fill the canvas with white before creating 2 paths - each one enclosing a purple area. If the track is closed, I'd fill with purple, then make a path that defined the outer ring of the track and fill this one with white. I'd then make another that defined the inner-edge of the track and fill it with purple. Beziers are reasonably easy to work with after a little practise. Presumably, someone's written an html app could draw the curves with before exporting the control-point co-ords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [Bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo) to draw the track. If drawing the current track segment on the fly is too slow, I would draw the whole track in a large hidden canvas and copy portions of it to the visible canvas.

The following snippet draws a segment that looks more or less like your example.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var width = 314,
      height = 645,
      canvas = document.getElementById('trackCanvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  context.lineWidth = width / 2;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(width / 2, 1.1 * height);
  context.bezierCurveTo(width / 2.2, height / 2.5,
                        width / 2.4, height / 4,
                        width, 0);
  context.stroke();
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#trackContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #b2bfdc;
}
#trackCanvas {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="trackContainer">
  <canvas id="trackCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```