# How do I make a running track or custom shape in HTML?

Tags: css, html

I am attempting to make a track and field app for high school and collegiate use, and would like to make a selectable track. I aim to be able to press each lane separately, how can I draw this shape out as well as make each lane individually pressed? Are there ways to make completely unique shapes in HTML?

The shape I currently have is something of a oval, a track obviously isn't an oval. One of my friends recommended using three shapes, two circles at the end and a rectangle in the center, and then making them all clickable.

[image]

That is the visual attempt at what I am attempting to accomplish, below is the less eye-appealing way

```css
.circle {
  height: 95px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!-- LANES -->
<h2>Lanes on Curve</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="lanes">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</form>

<h2>Lanes on Straight</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="lanes">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Related: [How to draw a running track on a canvas with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439749/how-to-draw-a-running-track-on-a-canvas-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I made this up pretty quick using absolute divs and offsetting the positioning of them depending on the track number. You can hover over the track and see the individual lane change color.

```css
.track-outer {
  position: relative;
}

.track { border: 10px solid #B27569; transition: all ease-in-out 200ms; position: absolute;}
.track:hover {border: 10px solid #825046; cursor:pointer}
.track:hover::before{ background:#825046;}

.track::before {content: ""; background:#B27569; height: 10px; position:absolute; bottom:-11px; width:100px; border-top:1px solid #fff; border-bottom:1px solid #fff; transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;}

/*  position changes by 11px every track, size changes by 22, border-rad by 10 */

.track1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius:100px;
  
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.track1::before {left: 0;}

.track2 {
  height: 178px;
  width: 428px;
  border-radius:90px;
  
  left:11px;
  top:11px;
}
.track2::before {left: -11px;}

.track3 {
  height: 156px;
  width: 406px;
  border-radius:80px;
  
  left:22px;
  top:22px;
}
.track3::before {left: -22px;}

.track4 {
  height: 134px;
  width: 384px;
  border-radius:70px;
  
  left:33px;
  top:33px;
}
.track4::before {left: -33px;}

.track5 {
  height: 112px;
  width: 362px;
  border-radius:60px;
  
  left:44px;
  top:44px;
}
.track5::before {left: -44px;}
```

```html
<div class="track-outer">
  
  <div class="track track1"></div>
  <div class="track track2"></div>
  <div class="track track3"></div>
  <div class="track track4"></div>
  <div class="track track5"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it will help make the app more user friendly. You're awesome!!